# ReactJS how to know which tag was click?

Tags: reactjs, key

I created an array of buttons tag and now I want to be able to handle each button when clicked but I dont know how to handle this.handleClickSelection() in order to know which tag has been clicked.

```
class Search extends React.Component
{
constructor()
{
    super();
    this.state = {  entries : [], entries_audio : [], }
}

componentWillMount()
{

    $.get( 'https://something', (data) => {


        var entriesArray = [];
        var entriesAudioArray  = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.stories.length ; i++) {
            entriesArray.push(<button className ="entries" key={i}  onClick={ ()=> this.handleClickSelection() } > {data.stories[i].title  }</button>);
            entriesAudioArray.push( data.stories[i] );
        };
        this.setState( { indents : entriesArray, entries_audio : entriesAudioArray  });
        console.log(this.state.entries_audio);



    }, 'json' );


}   


handleClickSelection()
{
    alert( "this particular button data");


}


//more code below
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind your click handler to the index:

```
... onClick={this.handleClickSelection.bind(this, i)}
```

and then `handleClickSelection` will receive the index as the first argument:

```
handleClickSelection(index, event) {
    console.log('item pressed: ', index);
}
```

Comment: thanks. it is working. Do you know why onClick={this.handleClickSelection.bind(this, i)} . works but onClick={ () => this.handleClickSelection.bind(this, i)} doesnt?

Comment: it's because in the second form you are not calling your click handler, `bind` just returns a new, bound function. if you want to write it like that you should just call your handler: `onClick={() => this.handleClickSelection(i)}`

Answer (score 1):

We use `bind` for this.  Like:

```
onClick={this.handleClickSelection.bind(this, i)}
```

Which will pass `i` as the first param into your method:

```
handleClickSelection(i)
```

Comment: thanks. it is working. Do you know why 

onClick={this.handleClickSelection.bind(this, i)} .  works but 


onClick={ () =>  this.handleClickSelection.bind(this, i)} doesnt?